# Error when writing to memory from DLL

Tags: c, dll, hook

I'm trying to change my `MessageBox` display on a program I have. I'm trying to do this by injecting a DLL and preforming a jump to my DLL from the `MessageBox` function which will cause my `MessageBox` to display instead of the regular one.

I have written the following code which gets the `MessageBox`'s address in memory and my `MessageBox`'s address as well, I'm trying to calculate the opcodes to preform the jump but unfortunately I receive a "*access violation*" error each time I inject the DLL, here is the code:

```
DWORD   oldProtect;

PVOID MessageBoxaddr = GetProcAddress(
    GetModuleHandle("User32.dll"), "MessageBoxA");
PVOID MessageBoxHookAddr = &HookedMessageBox;
DWORD relJmp = (DWORD)MessageBoxaddr- ((DWORD)MessageBoxHookAddr + 5);

VirtualProtect(MessageBoxaddr,
    sizeof(BYTE)* 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

// These line preform the little Debian method and are the cause for the error

((PBYTE)MessageBoxaddr)[0] = 0xe9;
((PBYTE)MessageBoxaddr)[1] = relJmp ^ 0x000000ff;
((PBYTE)MessageBoxaddr)[2] = (relJmp ^ 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
((PBYTE)MessageBoxaddr)[3] = (relJmp ^ 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
((PBYTE)MessageBoxaddr)[4] = (relJmp ^ 0xff000000)>>24;

VirtualProtect(MessageBoxaddr,
    sizeof(BYTE)* 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, &oldProtect);

return 0;
```

Comment: I suspect you mean `&` instead of `^`.  Then again I am not an expert in the little Debian method

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function as `MessageBox` in User32.dll

`MessageBox` is in fact a macro that resolves to either `MessageBoxA` or `MessageBoxW` depending on whether the preprocessor flag `UNICODE` is set.

So you can either target `MessageBoxA` or `MessageBoxW`, but `GetProcAddress(.., "MessageBox"`) will be returning `NULL`, `VirtualProtect` will be trying to change page access on a `NULL` pointer and that's why you're getting an Access Violation.

Also, you may want to use the Microsoft Detours library to do this instead of rolling your own code.

Comment: thanks!, i changed the function parameter to "MessageBoxA " but i still get the error. oh and i did try to use Microsoft Detours library at one point but it only works on x86 processes(unless you buy the full version)  and i need to preform the hook on an x64 process

Comment: Do you get the error as soon as the DLL is injected or after the detour tries to call MessageBoxA?

Comment: the DLL injects and when it finishes running over the code i showed the process crashes, i noticed that when i removed the lines that preform the little debian method the process doesn't crash so i'm guessing they are the cause for the error

Comment: Of course it won't crash if you remove those lines, since those are the lines that actually overwrite the memory. However ive never seen anyone write a jump like you have, usually when I do it it's something like `*(DWORD*)(jmp+1) = (DWORD)(src - jmp);` where jmp is a pointer to BYTE* for the hook function.